# Assigning name and account to BankAccount project

Tags: java

I'm almost in the home stretch for this project, and have hit an insurmountable speed bump. I have my main and a method below which looks something like this:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Proj3
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    { 
        BankAccount cust1 = new Proj3().createAccount();
        BankAccount cust2 = new Proj3().createAccount();
        BankAccount cust3 = new Proj3().createAccount();
        
             
    }
    
    public BankAccount createAccount() 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);   //input for Strings
        Scanner kb2 = new Scanner (System.in);  //input for numbers
        String strName;                         //Holds account name
        String strAccount;                      //Holds account number
        String strResponse;                     //Holds users response to account creation
        double dDeposit;                        //Holds intial deposit into checking
        BankAccount b1;
        
       
        
       
        {
            System.out.print ("\nWhat is the name of the account? ");
            strName = kb.nextLine();
            b1.setName(strName); 
            while (strName.length()==0)
            {
                System.out.print ("\nPlease input valid name.");

                System.out.print ("\nWhat is the name of the account?");
                strName = kb.nextLine();
            }

        System.out.print ("Would you like to create this account? (Y or N)");
        strResponse = kb.nextLine();
        strResponse = strResponse.toUpperCase();

        if (strResponse.equals("Y"))
        {
            BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(strName, strAccount, dDeposit);
        }
        else 
        {
            b1 = null;
        }
```

and I have a BankAccount class which looks something like this:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankAccount
{
   private String name;                       //Holds name of customer
   private String account;                    //Holds account number of 
   private double checkingAccount;            //Holds balance for checking
   private double savingsInterestRate;        //Holds annual interest rate on savings
   private double savingsAccount;             //Holds balance for savings
   private int savingsDays;                   //Holds days for calc. savings interest
   private double totalEarnedInterest;        //Holds total interest earned
   
   public BankAccount (String name, String account, double amount)
   {
       setName(name);
       setAccount(account);
       setChecking(amount);
   }
   
   public void setName (String name)
   {
       this.name = name;
   }
```

How would I pass all the users inputted information into their corresponding methods in my BankAccount class? In the end I'd like to use the toString method to display all the information on the screen.

I know the problem is `b1.setName(strName)` because I haven't initialized b1, but how would I go about doing that? Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but aren't you already doing that here: `BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(strName, strAccount, dDeposit);`?

Comment: @PaulRichter But he is calling setName on a null reference above. Why are you calling the setter there? Why not just remove that line?

Comment: You're calling setName() twice... once on an uninitialized instance of BankAccount (which throws NullPointer) and a second time when you are passing the String into the constructor. You're already doing what you're asking otherwise, now you just need to write the toString method and print out the class variables.

Comment: @PaulRichter The instructions were to get their name, account number, and then ask them if they want to create an account.  If they input Y, then I would create the account. If they input N then it would return null.

Comment: @ph0bolus Ok I spotted what thatidiotguy was talking about. Remove the `b1.setName(strName);` line. As others have said, how can you set a value on an object that does not exist yet? Simply hold the value in a variable, as you are currently doing, and only construct the `BankAccount` object when needed, passing in the values as I indicated you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the setName method of BankAcound before you create the object. The call to setName in not necessary since you are passing strName into the constructor.

Comment: I wanted to ask them for their name, and account number and if they wanted to create an account. It would create a new account for them using their information that they inputted. If they didn't want to create an account, it would jus return null.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to pass the arguments to your BankAccount constructor and assign member variables. You don't need to call setter methods from within a constructor.

```
public BankAccount(String name, String account, double amount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.account = account;
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

This way is ok if you have few arguments, but if you want to pass all your bank account properties to a constructor in a list of arguments, the code will become ugly and incomprehensible. It is easy to swap call parameters by mistake if they are of same type.

A more elegant approach is to use a fluent interface builder pattern, [as described here](http://architects.dzone.com/news/factories-builders-and-fluent-). Then creating a bank account object will look something like this:

```
BankAccount b1 = BankAccountBuilder.newBankAccount
            .witName(strName)
            .withAccountNumber(strAccount)
            .havingAmount(dDeposit)
            .withSavingDays(days)
            .build();
```